# Does trigonometric curves with imaginary period repeat itself?

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

The curve of $\cos x$ has period $2\pi$, so after every $2\pi$ the curve start to repeat itself, show in the blue line.

[image]

My question is, do all curves of sine and cosine start to repeat itself at some point?

Wolfram says that $\cos (x\ln2)$ has period 
\begin{align}
\frac{2i\pi}{\ln2}.
\end{align}

What does that mean? Does $\cos (x\ln2)$ repeat itself?

Query:

[image]

Comment: Cos(ax) has a period of 2pi/a, a can be a complex number as well

Comment: This answer with $i$ is unexpected. Did Wolfram use $i$ ? Can you show your query ?

Comment: @OscarLanzi: no what the OP reports is true !

Answer (score 1):

As $$\cos(x)=\cos(x+2\pi)$$ you also have

$$\cos(ax+b)=\cos(ax+b+2\pi)$$

or

$$\cos(ax+b)=\cos\left(a\left(x+\frac{2\pi}a\right)+b\right),$$

and that function has the period $\dfrac{2\pi}a$.

---

The answer by Wolfram seems wrong.

If we interpret $i$ as the imaginary number, then it is false that

$$\cos(x\log2+2i\pi)=\cos(x\log2).$$

And if we interpret $i$ as an arbitrary integer, then with the usual definition the *shortest* period is

$$\frac{2\pi}{\log2}$$ and there is no reason to multiply by $i$ (which could be zero !).

Comment: In English, unlike French, a space *never* precedes any of the following ? ! ; : ” (and the list should include — as well).

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish: do you mean?!;:"?

Comment: No, I don’t, because I wasn’t actually using them as punctuation there. I thought that was pretty clear.

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish: hahaha!

Answer (score 0):

In a general sense, a period is simply a number $p$ for which $f(x+p)=f(x)$ for all $x$. And that $p$ can be complex, like for the hyperbolic sine which has period $2i\pi$.

To answer you, it is true that all functions $\sin(ax+b)$ and $\cos(ax+b)$ have period $\frac{2\pi}a$, and $a$ can be complex. And Wolfram Alpha is wrong in that regard.

Comment: @OscarLanzi: to my big surprise, Wolfram seems wrong here.

Comment: Right, $a$ can be complex, but as far as I know, $\log 2$ is not.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes. I added that back into the answer.